# Cannot read a static file with d3.js in a Django template <script> tag

Tags: javascript, python, django, d3.js, django-templates

I'm using d3.js v3 for creating a Directed Graph in my Django template.
When I try to get data from a csv file as below,

```
d3.csv("file_name.csv", function(error, links) {
...
});
```

and use **links**, I get an error stating

> TypeError: links is undefined

Also in the command prompt I can see an error that **file_name.csv** could not be found. I'm suspecting it is looking for the file in some other location rather than in the template's directory itself. But I've tried putting the file in static folder as well and have had no luck.

**Note:** However, if I open the html template directly in a browser and have file_name.csv in the same directory, everything works fine and I can see the graph being created.

Comment: this JS code is executing on the client side (browser). Have a look at the Network tab or the webserver logs

Comment: The issue is d3.csv will make a Ajax call to load the csv. On your server it is unable to find the csv file. Try giving some route to the csv file.